# How to load font to combobox in C#?

Tags: c#

I using code here:
From I was search on StackOverflow:

```
List<string> fonts = new List<string>();

foreach (FontFamily font in System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families)
{
    fonts.Add(font.Name);
}
```

Updated:
I resolved my problem. I think this not best solution but it working for me.
Here:

```
private void cbxFontSize_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblFontSample.Font = new Font(lblFontSample.Font.FontFamily, Convert.ToInt32(cbxFontSize.SelectedItem), lblFontSample.Font.Style);
}

private void cbxFont_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        lblFontSample.Font = new Font(cbxFont.Text, lblFontSample.Font.Size);
    } 
    catch { }
}

private void frmConvertImage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (FontFamily fonts in FontFamily.Families)
    {
        cbxFont.Items.Add(fonts.Name.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to show your `cbxTextChanged` code? What is the error that you get?

Comment: I just added this code to combo box `cbxLoadFont_TextChanged`

Comment: That means you want to add it every time the text changed in the comboBox? I think you are going to the wrong direction... Try to check `cbxLoadFont.Items` instead. And you only need to add items to you comboBox once... Or else, don't trigger the add simply by `TextChanged`, you may want to consider using `Button_Click` instead

Comment: Thanks @lan. My problem is resolved. I updated my question.

Comment: Other than the empty catch block that is swallowing any exception it looks fine to me - what do you not like about it?

Comment: You will remove it or throw exception @DStanley?

Comment: What kind of exception would you expect the code to throw?  If you know of a specific exception that _could_ happen but you can't do anything about it, then ignore that one but don't ignore ALL exceptions.

Comment: Ok. I understand your answer